# Visual Studio 2010 data connections missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I opened vs2010 this morning and all my data connections (in server explorer) were missing. I had a quite a list so this is a real pain. They're solution/project independent so I'm not sure why they'd just clear.  Any ideas?  I shut VS down properly last night too.

Cheers,

Andy.

Comment: Come on. Someone must know something!! There's a lot of clever people out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me today too. I wasn't able to figure out what caused that, so I simply restored the **DefaultView.SEView** file from the last disk backup and all my connections came back.. phew. That file is stored in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer`, so you might want to periodically backup it just in case. Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Oops, didn't get/see an email to say I'd got a response. Thanks for the tip.  I had a copy from before the bomb, but I've largely recreated them now anyway.  Useful one to remember.  Thanks.